# How can I disable the history swipe action in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, desktop

I am creating a browser-based desktop application with a text view.  The text view may contain long horizontal lines.  In Chrome, doing a left swipe on a track pad will sometimes activate the history.back action and sometimes activate the scroll left action.  This is more than a little annoying for our users.

How do I disable the history swipe actions so that swiping will only scroll?

Note that I already supply a custom pushstate event handler. And also that moving forward/backward in history has appropriate meaning in the app, so I can't just disable history.

Comment: I don't really see a way you can. Hope there is a way, though, because I can see this being a problem

Comment: Thanks.  I also came across this discussion: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/PaMriZC-Kuo So, it seems like this is a problem not just for particular web apps.

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5616407?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've seen, there is no officially-sanctioned way to fix this. Toggling swipe gestures is regulated at the system level, not at the browser, so the only way to disable them is to do so manually in the system preferences (turn off "swipe between pages" in System Preferences -> Trackpad -> More Gestures).

However, after searching for a little while, I stumbled upon a hack that uses JQuery's mousewheel.js to override the settings.

[This plugin by Pablo Villalba of Teambox](https://github.com/micho/jQuery.preventMacBackScroll) was the first implementation I found when searching for a plugin that implements such an override. Hope this helps.

Comment: Fantastic.  Looking forward to trying this.

Comment: I tried this out.  And it works as you describe, so thanks.  However, I don't know if I will use this particular jquery plugin since it requires several other libraries to be installed into my app that I don't want.  That being said, this plugin shows a work around and I may use this to create my own version.

Comment: One final update here.  Since I don't want to introduce jquery into this project, I did a simpler workaround.  I capture the mouseWheel event and call e.preventDefault() if on mac-chrome.  We already have custom scrolling handled, so preventing the default behavior does not seem to have any adverse effect.

Comment: For anyone searching sake, here is the solutions in another discussion at [Superuser.com 840102](http://superuser.com/questions/840102/how-do-you-disable-swipe-history-navigation), you can disable the `overscroll` in `chrome://flag` settings page or pass `--overscroll-history-navigation=0` arguments/parameters when starting chrome

Comment: @simongcc Beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

On mac i disabled swipe between pages under System preferences.
[image: Swipe Between Pages]

Comment: This is not the same feature. What you did was disable switching between apps. I was looking to disable back history navigation on chrome.

Comment: It does work even on chrome too if set at root level. I have highlighted correct line "Swipe between pages" => Scroll left or right with 2 finger.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not what I was looking for. I needed a way to automatically disable this feature for users of my webapp, and only that app. I can't ask my users to turn this feature off in system preferences whenever they want to use my app.

Comment: Oh. Well let me know too if u have a solution in future but it seems more like OS thing adapted by browser instead of specific webapp or site thing but this OS feature is seriously terrible.

Comment: See some of the comments on the accepted answer. There is a jquery plugin that works and I created an adapted solution out of that. But, there are performance concerns with handling mouseWheel events.